# How to connect to WPA_EAP WIFI on Android with 4.3 API

Tags: java, android, wifi, android-4.3-jelly-bean, wpa

Recently Android added the ability to connect to EAP WIFI with API 18 (JellyBean 4.3). I have looked for a number of examples, but can't find any examples, and I can't get my code to connect. Everything appears to work as expected, but making the actual connection doesn't seem to work.

Here is what I'm doing:

```
Log.d( "WiFi", "adding network via Android Enterprise Config with SSID: " + ssid );
                    WifiEnterpriseConfig enterpriseConfig = new WifiEnterpriseConfig(); 
                    wifiConfig = new WifiConfiguration();
                    wifiConfig.SSID = ssid; 

                    enterpriseConfig.setIdentity(userName);
                    enterpriseConfig.setPassword(passWord);
                    enterpriseConfig.setEapMethod(WifiEnterpriseConfig.Eap.PEAP); 
                    wifiConfig.enterpriseConfig = enterpriseConfig;
                    Log.i("WIFI", "My wifi"+ wifiConfig.status); 
                    networkId = wfm.addNetwork(wifiConfig);

                    wfm.enableNetwork(networkId, true); // this initiates the connection
```

For whatever reason the connection isn't made. It appears that everything else is set correctly. If I've left anything out, let me know and I'll happily add it.

Any help or direction would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You need to set the key management

```
   WifiEnterpriseConfig enterpriseConfig = new WifiEnterpriseConfig(); 
   wifiConfig = new WifiConfiguration();
   wifiConfig.SSID = ssid; 
   wifiConfig.allowedKeyManagement.set(KeyMgmt.WPA_EAP);
   wifiConfig.allowedKeyManagement.set(KeyMgmt.IEEE8021X);
   enterpriseConfig.setIdentity(userName);
   enterpriseConfig.setPassword(passWord);
   enterpriseConfig.setEapMethod(WifiEnterpriseConfig.Eap.PEAP); 
   wifiConfig.enterpriseConfig = enterpriseConfig;
```

Comment: @Blaine are you able to connect to EAP by using above code ? I am able to save configuration but not able to connect.

Comment: @sankar Yes, I was about to connect using this. But you also have to use the code that I had above. Combine the two to make the connection.

Comment: can we use same for eap of sim type?