# connect wpa2 enterprise wifi connection programmatically in android

Tags: android, android-wifi, wifimanager, wifi

I just tried few codes for wpa2 enterprise connection in android but nothing is connecting i want a right code to connect the right network. right now i have used this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4374862/how-to-programmatically-create-and-read-wep-eap-wifi-configurations-in-android/4374934#4374934) but i need few clarification because this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4374862/how-to-programmatically-create-and-read-wep-eap-wifi-configurations-in-android/4374934#4374934) is very old one. here i am attaching some screenshot about connection clarification. 
In this [image: screenshot] you can see **identity** and **password**

```
  WifiConfiguration wifiConfiguration = new WifiConfiguration();
        wifiConfiguration.SSID = "\"" + networkSSID + "\"";
        wifiConfiguration.BSSID = Bssid;
        wifiConfiguration.hiddenSSID = true;
        wifiConfiguration.status = WifiConfiguration.Status.DISABLED;
        wifiConfiguration.allowedKeyManagement.set(WifiConfiguration.KeyMgmt.WPA_EAP);
        wifiConfiguration.allowedKeyManagement.set(WifiConfiguration.KeyMgmt.IEEE8021X);
        wifiConfiguration.allowedProtocols.set(WifiConfiguration.Protocol.RSN);
        wifiConfiguration.allowedProtocols.set(WifiConfiguration.Protocol.WPA);
        wifiConfiguration.allowedAuthAlgorithms.set(WifiConfiguration.AuthAlgorithm.SHARED);
        wifiConfiguration.allowedPairwiseCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.PairwiseCipher.CCMP);
        wifiConfiguration.allowedPairwiseCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.PairwiseCipher.TKIP);
        wifiConfiguration.enterpriseConfig.setIdentity(identity);
        wifiConfiguration.enterpriseConfig.setPassword(password);

        wifiConfiguration.allowedGroupCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.GroupCipher.CCMP);
        wifiConfiguration.allowedGroupCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.GroupCipher.TKIP);

       if (networkPasskey.matches("^[0-9a-fA-F]+$")) {
            wifiConfiguration.wepKeys[0] = networkPasskey;
        } else {
            wifiConfiguration.wepKeys[0] = "\"".concat(networkPasskey).concat("\"");
        }
        wifiConfiguration.wepTxKeyIndex = 0;
```

i have found enterprice function in wificonfiguration to set identity and password.

```
    wifiConfiguration.enterpriseConfig.setIdentity(identity);
    wifiConfiguration.enterpriseConfig.setPassword(password);
```

but what is the use of this one. when we have identity and password.

```
if (networkPasskey.matches("^[0-9a-fA-F]+$")) {
        wifiConfiguration.wepKeys[0] = networkPasskey;
    } else {
        wifiConfiguration.wepKeys[0] = "\"".concat(networkPasskey).concat("\"");
    }
    wifiConfiguration.wepTxKeyIndex = 0;
```

i am using **BSSID** because my AP have same ssid so i want to connect the right network by using **BSSID**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have solved it by the help of this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19236537/1835764)

```
  WifiConfiguration config = new WifiConfiguration();
    config.SSID = "\"" + networkSSID + "\"";
    config.BSSID = Bssid;
    config.priority = 1;
 String networkIdentity = "";
         networkPasskey = "";
        config.status = WifiConfiguration.Status.ENABLED;
        WifiEnterpriseConfig enterpriseConfig = new WifiEnterpriseConfig();
        config.allowedKeyManagement.set(WifiConfiguration.KeyMgmt.WPA_EAP);
        config.allowedKeyManagement.set(WifiConfiguration.KeyMgmt.IEEE8021X);
        enterpriseConfig.setIdentity(networkIdentity);
        enterpriseConfig.setPassword(networkPasskey);
        enterpriseConfig.setEapMethod(WifiEnterpriseConfig.Eap.PEAP);
        enterpriseConfig.setPhase2Method(WifiEnterpriseConfig.Phase2.MSCHAPV2);
        config.enterpriseConfig = enterpriseConfig;
   WifiManager myWifiManager = (WifiManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
    int id = myWifiManager.addNetwork(config);
    Log.d("addNetwork", "# addNetwork returned " + id);

    myWifiManager.enableNetwork(id, true);
```

but this method will work till android 7.0 in android 8.0 they have restricted many function we can not add wifi configuration manually.

three things we must know when you are trying to configure with **wpa2 enterprise**

1. you must know the **EAP** method it can be anything but mostly they will use **PEAP**

2.you must know about the **Phase2** method, mostly they will use **MSCHAPV2**

3. **Certificate** this one maximum **Do Not validate**.